# Why do i need a developer account for AWS Codestar?

Tags: amazon-web-services

If i want to use codestar, I need to create a developer account, which is probably pretty weird. But it is even more weird, that i get redirected to creating an Amazon account.

Can anyone explain me why this is the case?

Comment: Do you mean AWS CodeStar? Why do you find it "weird" that an Amazon Web Service requires an Amazon Web Services account?

Comment: AWS requires an Amazon account.

Comment: Yes. Because Amazon is the company that provides Amazon Web Services, CodeStar being one of them.

Comment: It makes no sense to create an additonal account for no reason, so there must be a decent reason and there is: i had alexa skill selected

Comment: What do you mean by "developer account"? Developer support plan?

Comment: I do not mean anything with it. It was called that way.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pay attention to the application type

[image]

Select the right application type and AWS service in the template section
[image]

For example, if you chose AWS EC2 and Web application, AWS won't ask you for an Amazon developer account